# Next action using analytic functions

Tags: sql, oracle, analytic-functions

For the need of a cohort analysis, I'm trying to get the next action of each customer (unsubscription, upgrade, downgrade...)

I have a monhtly snapshot with the following data :

```
customer | month      | last_action   | last_action_date
1          01-01-2012   subscription    01-01-2012
1          02-01-2012   subscription    01-01-2012
1          03-01-2012   subscription    01-01-2012
1          04-01-2012   downgrade       04-01-2012
1          05-01-2012   downgrade       04-01-2012
1          06-01-2012   downgrade       04-01-2012
1          07-01-2012   unsubscription  07-01-2012
```

As you can see, the action is known only at the month it is done, at the month 01-01-2012 we don't know yet the customer downgraded in 04-01-2012 so we can't analyse his usage behavior relative to his downgrade month. Same thing for unsubscription.

The needed dataset is the following :

```
customer | month      | downgrade_date   | unsubscription_date
1          01-01-2012   04-01-2012         07-01-2012
1          02-01-2012   04-01-2012         07-01-2012
1          03-01-2012   04-01-2012         07-01-2012
1          04-01-2012   12-31-9999         07-01-2012
1          05-01-2012   12-31-9999         07-01-2012
1          06-01-2012   12-31-9999         07-01-2012
1          07-01-2012   12-31-9999         07-01-2012
```

I could have easily the unsubscription date with the last_value analytic function but didn't find a way to get the downgrade date.

Here is my SQL Query :

```
SELECT month_id, 
       customer_id,
       CASE 
         WHEN LAST_VALUE(last_action) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY month_id RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) = 'unsubscription' THEN LAST_VALUE(last_action_date) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY month_id RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)    
         ELSE TO_DATE('99991231', 'yyyymmdd')
       END unsubscription_date
FROM my_table
;
```

Any way to get the "next" action date like in the "downgrade_date".

I'm using Oracle.

Comment: Check out the `lead()` function.

Answer (score 1):

In oracle 11, you can do this with `lead()` and the `ignore nulls` option:

```
select customer, MONTH,
       lead(case when last_action = 'downgrade' then last_action_date end ignore nulls) over
                 (partition by customer order by month desc) as downgrade_date,
       lead(case when last_action = 'unsubscription' then last_action_date end ignore nulls) over
                 (partition by customer order by month desc) as downgrade_date,
from my_table t
```

If you don't have `ignore nulls`, you can do something similar with `min()`:

```
select customer, MONTH,
       min(case when last_action = 'downgrade' then last_action_date end) over
                (partition by customer order by month range between current and unbounded following
                ) as downgrade_date,
       min(case when last_action = 'unsubscription' then last_action_date end) over
                (partition by customer order by month range between current and unbounded following
                ) as unsubscription_date
from my_table t
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, the min() query doesn't work and the problem with lead is that I get the downgrade_date only on the one row preceding the downgrade and following.

Comment: @user2018454 . . . My guess is that the `lead()` query does work because of Oracle versions.  The `min()` was ordering by `month desc` and then taking everything to the end -- meaning it was looking at earlier months.  Remove `desc` and see if that works.